# Aes multibit hd decryption openssl

Tags: openssl, aes

I am trying to decrypt my old multibit HD wallet to recuperate half BTC in it. I tried openssl without success.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in mbhd.wallet.aes -out mbhd.txt
```

Something I missed surely, no ?

Thx for your help

Comment: You need to specify `-d` to decrypt. Also, did you encrypt it before, or fairly soon after, 2016? If so you probably used OpenSSL 1.0.x or even 0.9.x, but may now be using 1.1.x, which defaults the PBKDF hash differently. See 'Inter-version compatibility' at (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 . This is not a programming question or issue.

Comment: thank you @dave_thompson_085 for your answer. The wallet have been created in 2016,. The 1st transaction was in january. 2016, so may be I have to downgrade openssl. For me, it's the opportunity to learn about encryption. I am beginner with python. It's not a programming issue, you're right. I am gonna move the post.

Comment: @ dave_thompson_085, unfortunately, I couldn't downgrade openssl on my mac

Comment: You don't need to downgrade, just use `-md md5` on 1.1.x to match the behavior of lower versions, as explained at the link I gave you

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, Sorry I missed that point. So now, I have "bad magic number" as return. However, I am sure of password. Is it possible that the file has been "corrupted" or "broken" ?

Comment: 'bad magic' means (1) the file is actually base64-encoded but you didn't specify `-a` on the decrypt; look at the file to determine (2) the encryption did not use salt; look at the file, or the result of base64-decoding the file, to see if it begins with the exact characters `Salted__` (3) the file wasn't encrypted with `openssl enc` at all but by some other means; in this case get a hexdump of the file and show an initial part -- 16-32 bytes is usually enough. FYI wrong password _or_ kdf-hash with cbc would usually cause 'bad padding' but never 'bad magic'.

Comment: Thank you Dave for the explanation and your help. I really appreciate. I am gonna look at this and try to solve the issue :) Merry Easter !